# Is it safe to delete performance session files for visual studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Is it safe to delete performance session files for Visual Studio 2012?

I did profiling, and removed the session files only from the project but
they were not deleted from the project directory. Now I have huge files, around 8 GB
with extensions `.psess`, `.vsp` and `.vspx`, and I am not sure if it is safe to manually delete
them.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, if you no longer need your performance reports, you can delete them. You can either delete them from the file system directly or, if you prefer using the Performance Explorer in Visual Studio, you can delete your reports from there as well.

Comment: You can always just delete them from explorer directly. I mentioned Performance Explorer because if you delete a file while it is still linked from Performance Explorer, it will show a dialog telling you that the file is missing and ask if you want it removed from Performance Explorer as well.

Answer (score 0):

If they are removed from the project, and the program still works normally, you should be safe to delete them.  If you want to be safe about it, try moving the files to a temporary folder and see if it messes things up without it. If no problems, continue on with the deletion.

Comment: I would not play like that, it may not mess things up instantly but maybe something will mess up later. I would rather get an answer from someone if he knows definitely whether this is safe or not.